# How to change users in kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my machine I have two `kubectl` users, my company's account and my personal account. I can confirm that by running `kubectl config view`.

I'm trying to access my company's cluster but `kubectl` is using to my personal credentials to authenticate. Which is causing an error, as expected.

How do I change to my company's account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users and clusters are tied to a context and you can change users and clusters by changing the context.

```
kubectl config use-context my-context-name
```

Above command sets the current context to `my-context-name`.Now when kubectl is used the user and cluster tied to `my-context-name` context will be used.

Check the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) for more details and various other available options.